# A Better Regex Solution in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Here's my problem:

I have text files with five columns. The last always has a single digit. Backslashes are illegal in the first three. Spaces may show up in the first column. I remove everything after the last @ in the first column. The columns are separated by spaces. I can set the column width to pretty much any value I want, giving me some control as to the spacing between columns.

So, I might have something like this:

```
D Smith     Application     Database     Read     2
```

I have code that transforms it into this:

```
grant read on database 'Application'.'Database' to 'D Smith';
```

Here is the Regex code I have created to delimit each field and avoid confusing any spaces in the first field from the delimiting spacing.

```
while (<>) {
    s/^ //m;
    if (/^([^\\]+?)( {80,})/) {
        my $atindex = rindex($1,"@",);
        my $username = substr($1,0,$atindex);
        if ($atindex != -1) {
            s/^([^\\]+?)( {80,})/$username  $2/m;
            s/ {2,}/ \\ \\ /g;
            s/\\ \d$//gm;
            s/ \\ $//gm;
        }
    }
```

What this does is make `\\ \\` the delimiter between fields. Then I use this code for the transformation:

```
if (/([^\\]+) \\ \\ ([^\\]+) \\ \\ ([^\\]+) \\ \\ ([^\\]+)\n/) {
    if ($4 eq "any") {
        my $execany = "execute any";
        print "grant $execany on database '$2'.'$3' to user '$1';\n";
    } else {
        print "grant $4 on database '$2'.'$3' to user '$1';\n";
    }
```

I'm doing this because I couldn't figure out a way to discern the spaces between the fields from the spaces that might occur in the first field. Is there a better way? This works sufficiently quickly, but it's not elegant.

Comment: Given that you control the column spacing, why not delimit on `\s{2,}` -- that is, at least two spaces -- and space the columns accordingly?

Comment: Actually, I can't control the spacing directly. It's indirect: I can control the column width. I'll edit my post.

Comment: The point is that you have control over the number of spaces between columns, sufficient to ensure that that number is always greater than one for any given pair of columns. Assuming that's true, you can split on any string of two or more spaces and get the result you're after.

Comment: Does that mean I have to change my search term: [^\\]+ because that picks up multiple spaces?

Comment: It means you no longer have any need to do all that brittle and flaky business of replacing spaces with backslashes. In fact, you need not use a complex regular expression at all; I'll shortly post an answer giving an example of what I mean by that.

Comment: Regular expressions are not "complex" if you use them right. This problem is not difficult. The simple solution is to match the last four columns from the right. What's left is everything in the first column, no matter how many spaces it has. Don't be fooled by long and complicated solutions, this can be solved in a few simple lines. See below for a short solution that works.

Comment: @grebneke You just keep beating this horse, don't you? The *simple*, and also more general, solution is to define a reliable column delimiter, `split()` on that, and work from there with the array of values you get from that. I say "simple", because "break this string up by that delimiter" is conceptually simpler than the regex you're pushing, and "general", because the `split()` method works no matter how many columns there are, or which columns contain spaces -- neither of which may matter to the asker, but both of which will certainly matter in cases other than his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I describe in the comments to your question, as long as you can ensure that two simple assumptions are valid, you have no need for a lot of complicated hairy regexing. Those assumptions are:

- that, for every pair of columns, at least two spaces separate the end of the value in the first column, and the beginning of the value in the second;
- that no column's value contains a string of two or more spaces.

(If you can't guarantee those assumptions for a separator consisting of two or more spaces, perhaps you can for three or more, or four or more, &c. You're better off delimiting your columns with something that you can be certain will never appear in any value, but absent that, rules like these are the best you can hope to do.)

Given those assumptions, you can just `split()` the string on substrings of two or more spaces, something like this:

```
while (<>) {
      $_ =~ s@^\s+@@;
      my @fields = split(/\s{2,}/, $_);
      # print your commands, interpolating values from @fields
}
```

Or, more simply and readably still, you can do something like this:

```
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    # the same leading-space cleanup and split...
    $line =~ s@^\s+@@;
    my @fields = split(/\s{2,}/, $line);

    # ...and then we assign values to a hash with meaningful keys...
    my %values = ('user'        => $fields[0],
                  'application' => $fields[1],
                  'database'    => $fields[2],
                  'permission'  => (lc($fields[3]) eq 'any'
                                      ? 'execany'
                                      : $fields[3]));

    # ...so that our interpolation and printing becomes much more
    # readable.
    print "grant $values{'permission'}"
      . " on database '$values{'application'}'.'$values{'database'}"
      . " to user '$values{'user'}';"
      . "\n";
};
```

You'd do well also to add some validity checking, i.e. make sure all the values you expect in a given row are present and correctly formatted and emit some useful notice, or just `die()` outright, if they're not.

Comment: I missed the two+ spaces between fields; in this case, `split` is a better option.  No need to use the default scalar here, nor the substitution.  Consider just simplifying to `my @fields = grep $_, split /\s{2,}/;`.

Comment: Why the extra step of assigning values to a hash instead of just assigning the results of `split` to 'meaningful' vars?

Comment: @Kenosis Your suggested "simplification" complicates, in that it leaves the underscore variable implicit and thus requires more cognitive effort to figure out what it's actually doing. It also makes validation more difficult as well by collapsing empty fields -- with your suggestion, I can tell if not every field in a row lacks a value, but I can no longer tell *which* field lacks a value, which is useful information when I'm trying to figure out why the value is missing in the first place.

Comment: @Kenosis (I do appreciate your calling attention to my sloppiness in having used the implicit variable at all in my second code example; I never permit myself that laziness in my own code, but failed to expunge it in my expansion of the asker's code here. I've since edited my answer to do so.)

Comment: @Kenosis The use of a hash instead of four scalars simplifies future changes to the algorithm; perhaps instead of simply spitting out GRANT statements, I might later decide I want to sort and filter these records, or serialize them, or use them for some as yet entirely unimagined purpose. Using a hash (or, as I'd usually prefer, a hashref) from the start greatly simplifies anything I may later do with those values, and doesn't require significant extra effort which would be wasted in case I never do anything else with those values after all.

Comment: *Your suggested "simplification" complicates, in that it leaves the underscore variable implicit and thus requires more cognitive effort to figure out what it's actually doing.*  I disagree, especially when you have a `while (<>) { ...` construct.  *Rarely* do I ever see Perl's default scalar explicitly used in such cases.

Comment: @Kenosis You're right about `while (<>)`, which is frankly never acceptable; per one of my replies to your earlier comments, I've since rather shamefacedly expunged that abuse of the language from my answer. This also has the pleasant side effect of strengthening my argument against `grep $_, split /\s{2,}/;`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, the code still doesn't do exactly what I need it to. The last digit is still not accounted for. Also, some lines are missing values in some fields and other lines aren't data, but are text headers that just need to be deleted outright. But this does give me a new insight on how to work with data. So thanks!

Comment: Actually, now that we've changed while(<>), it doesn't finish running.

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complex. A simple, beautiful regex solves the problem in a single line.

Comment: @DrewRush Re: the last digit not being handled, that's because your original code didn't seem to do anything with it, either. In my second example, you'd find it in `$fields[4]`. The cases of missing values, and of header rows, are the sort of thing which can be handled by the validation I mentioned. If the change from `while (<>)` produces an infinite loop, then there's something else weird in your code; either form should exit the loop once STDIN is exhausted. I'd be interested to see it in the context of your script as a whole, assuming that's not too long to edit into your question;

Comment: @grebneke This answer is both simpler and more readable than that which satisfies what I can only regard as your warped sense of beauty; fifteen years of hacking Perl has taught me to favor the explicit over the implicit, and the simple over the complex, both of which considerations militate against using regular expressions which are even one byte longer than they have to be. (It's not that I don't understand where you're coming from; it's just that years and years of fighting with overly complex regexes has taught me the value of [jwz's dictum](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).)

Comment: It seems fifteen years have gone by and you haven't been bothered to learn regular expressions which are at the heart and soul of Perl. So much that many other languages have adopted them (preg in PHP, Ruby, Javascript etc). Your loss.

Comment: @grebneke You confuse understanding of regular expressions with an incontinent habit of favoring them as the only thing worth using. As for any tool, a correct understanding of regular expressions encompasses knowing when *not* to use them.

Comment: *This answer is both simpler and more readable...*  This 'readability' is purely subjective, as I find both quite (subjectively) 'readable.'  There's a risk of over-generalizing jwz's dictum, as there exists fuzzy cases where either or both will work well.

Comment: @Kenosis Granted that either answer is about as "readable" for someone who is very familiar with Perl regexes. Many of my colleagues, skilled programmers all, lack such intimate familiarity, and I don't see why they should be expected to spend a week with *Mastering Regular Expressions* just to understand my contributions to shared codebases. (To say nothing of the fact that any competent web developer understands the value of robustness in input-parsing code, and if code brittleness scales linearly with complexity, then regex brittleness scales geometrically.)

Comment: *...regex brittleness...*  The `split` we've used is driven by an inherently 'brittle' regex--one that needs two+ spaces as a field delimiter.  If this changes, the `split` fails.  However, [grebneke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2061321/grebneke)'s regex will keep capturing those fields--whether delimited by one or more spaces.  Thus, it's inherently more robust than the `split` we've used.

Comment: @Kenosis The asker's stated ability to control the column width, and thereby the nature of the "delimiter," obviates that argument. In a case where such control wasn't available to whoever had to write code to parse that data, you'd have a point, although see [my other comment on that case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862499/a-better-regex-solution-in-perl/20863136?noredirect=1#comment31304022_20863876) for a method of handling it without resorting to the complicated regex.

Comment: *The asker's stated ability to control the column width, and thereby the nature of the "delimiter," obviates that argument.*  Does it?  It only takes a minor change by the OP (or someone other than the OP) and the `split`'s toast.  I'm hesitant to place so much literal faith in the OP's control over the delimiter--even though I did.  The regex obviates all need for such faith, as it'll happily capture all fields as needed.

Comment: @Kenosis Granted -- but, again, there is a solution to that case which doesn't entail the technical debt of a complicated regex; e.g. `unshift @fields, join(' ', (shift @fields, shift @fields)) if length(@fields) == 6` isn't any prettier, but it's a lot more obvious what's actually going on, especially for someone who doesn't live and breathe regexes, as my colleagues don't, and as I no longer do (and find I'm much happier for it).

Comment: The original code deals with the last digit character here: `s/\\ \d$//gm;`

Comment: @AaronMiller, see last comment about the digit. Also: "If the change from while (<>) produces an infinite loop, then there's something else weird in your code;" I *only* used your code. I copied it in its entirety and ran only it.

Comment: @DrewRush Oh, I see -- again, you'll find the last digit in `$fields[4]`, if you care to do anything with it, and it may otherwise be safely ignored. As for the filehandle change -- oh, wow, I thought `<>` was an alias for `<STDIN>`, but instead apparently there's some magic there which implicitly opens each file listed on the command line in turn. (This is why I stopped liking Perl quite so much; too much magic makes it hard to understand what the hell's going on.) `while (my $line = <>)` should work.

Answer (score 5):

Are the columns constant width? If so, skip the regular expression and simply use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

#### Data Format

```
D Smith     Application     Database     Read     2
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

#### Program

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

while ( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    ( my $user = substr( $line, 0, 10 )) =~ s/\s*$//;
    ( my $file = substr( $line, 12, 15 )) =~ s/\s*$//;
    ( my $db   = substr( $line, 28, 12 )) =~ s/\s*$//;
    ( my $op   = substr( $line, 41, 9 )) =~ s/\s*$//;
    ( my $num  = substr ( $line, 50 )) =~ s/\s*$//;
    say qq(User = "$user", File = "$file", DB = "$db", OP = "$op", NUM = "$num");
}
```

The `s/\s*$//;` trims the right side of the string removing white space.

If you don't want to use all of those substrings, and only your first field might have a space in it, then you can use `substr` to split out that first field, and [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on the rest of the fields:

```
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    ( my $user = substr( $line, 0, 10 ) ) =~ s/\s*$//;
    my ( $file, $db, $op, $num ) = split /\s+/, substr( $line, 12 );
    ....
}
```

---

### Another Solution

> Are the columns constant width? ... Nice solution. unpack could also be used with constant widths. – Kenosis

Let's use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)!

```
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $user, $file, $db, $op, $num ) = unpack ("A12A16A13A9A*", $line);
    say qq(User = "$user", File = "$file", DB = "$db", OP = "$op", NUM = "$num");
}
```

Yes, that's easy to understand. At least I don't have to *right trim* my strings like I did with `substr`. See the [pack/unpack tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html).

Comment: *Are the columns constant width? ...*  Nice solution.  `unpack` could also be used with constant widths.

Comment: @Kenosis Yes, that is true, and I could do it in one go. The problem is pack is hard. It makes my brain hurt and those who have to maintain my script never understand what I'm doing. So, I tend to skip over it. Come to think of it, this is really an _unpack_.

Comment: I rarely use `pack `or `unpack`, but have used the latter for fixed width fields.  When I did, though, it also made my brain hurt.

Comment: Excellent, David!  Your `unpack` solution is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

To match lines like this:

```
D Smith      Application     Database     Read     2
F J Perl     Foobar          Database2    Write    4
Something    Whatever        Database3    Any      1
```

into the relevant columns 1 to 5, where column 1 can contain spaces, anchor on end-of-line (`$`):

```
while (<>) {
    next unless /^\s*(.+?)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)$/;
    my $grant_type = $4;
    $grant_type = 'execute any' if lc $grant_type eq 'any';
    print "grant $grant_type on '$2'.'$3' to '$1'\n";
}
```

result:

```
grant Read on 'Application'.'Database' to 'D Smith'
grant Write on 'Foobar'.'Database2' to 'F J Perl'
grant execute any on 'Whatever'.'Database3' to 'Something'
```

Comment: I downvoted it, and hadn't gotten around to commenting in explanation. The reason I downvoted it, both in your case and in the case of another answer since deleted, is the same reason why it's erroneous to describe a godawful regex like that one as "simple"; it is in fact far more complex than the situation requires, not to mention being just generally godawful ugly besides -- and don't think you managed to sneak that "only accept spaces in the first column" behavior past me, either! That's precisely the sort of thing that gives Perl, and Perl programmers, a bad name in the wider community.

Comment: Regexps are at the heart of Perl. They are elegant and useful.

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but it may be because I inititially offered a regex almost identical to yours.  Matching from the right's the trick if you don't want to rely upon the fields being separated by two+ spaces.  This being said, the OP did want to change the permission var if it was "any", so you'd need to accommodate for that.

Comment: @grebneke Perl regexes are often useful. They are very rarely elegant.

Comment: @Kenosis, thanks you're right. Edited my post. Also the OP has different format in the question, one says 'grant Read on' and the other is 'grant Read on database'. It's easy enough to adjust the code if needed.

Comment: The OP's specs weren't initially too clear to me.  [Aaron Miller](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1713079/aaron-miller) correctly saw the two+ spaces field delimiter, which does lend itself well to a `split`, but the regex is actually more robust, not requiring that two-space delimiter constraint.

Comment: @Kenosis The asker has control of the column width, which means he's able to ensure the field delimiter. (And, assuming a single-space delimiter and data with only one column that might contain spaces, you can still dodge the ugly regex by checking `length(@fields)` and doing `unshift @fields, join(' ', (shift @fields, shift @fields))` if you got one more field than you expected. I grant that's merely a different flavor of ugly, but some ugliness is to be expected in code which has to deal with in-band delimiters like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Given you have two+ spaces between fields, perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my ( $user, $app, $db, $perm ) = grep $_, split /\s{2,}/;
    $perm = 'execute any' if lc $perm eq 'any';

    print "grant $perm on database '$app'.'$db' to user '$user';\n";
}
```

You can omit the initial-space substitution by `grep`ping the result of `split`.  `$perm` is changed only if it's `any` after the `split`.

Comment: This produces an uninitialized variable error for the four variables after my.

Answer (score 0):

As you say only the first column contains spaces we can use split to break up the columns,
and splice to remove the last four... Then just use string interpolation to re-constitute
the first column - no complex repular expressions required, no assumptions about fixed
column spacing and no assumptions about double spacing.. Probably want to add some more
validity checks (make sure values are valid)

```
use strict;
use Const::Fast qw(const);
const my $N => 4;

while(<>){
  ## Split the string on spaces...
  chomp;
  my @Q = split;
  next if @Q <= $N;

  ## And remove the last four columns...
  my ($app,$db,$perm,$flag) = splice @Q,-$N,$N;

  ## Sort out name and perm...
  ( my $user = "@Q" ) =~ s{@[^@]+}{}mxs;
  $perm = 'execute any' if 'any' eq lc $perm;

  ## Print out statement... using named variables makes life easier!
  print "grant $perm on database '$app'.'$db' to user '$user';\n";
}
```